# Grails hasOne association

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What is the difference between these 2 hasOne syntax ?

```
class Project {
.......
............
    static hasOne = Employee

  //  static hasOne = [employee:Employee]
}
```

I have noticed that the first one creates a many-to-many relationship(3 tables) but it should be many-to-one(2 tables) as in the Employee class I have:

```
static hasMany = [projects:Project]
```

The second one works fine:

```
static hasOne = [employee:Employee]
```

I am using Grails 2.2.0 and I even tried in Grails 2.0.3 but the result is same.

Thanks

Comment: Database schemas are somehow different because of these two things. You may check by grails schema-export the differences in databases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the 1st variant makes any sense at all. You could define a `belongsTo` back-ref without specifying a field for that, and this could be used for cascading things for example.

The case with `hasOne` is quite the opposite: you want to have an explicit one-to-one, which makes it logical to specify the reference explicitly:

```
static hasOne = [employee:Employee]
```

The most common case to use `hasOne` is when you want to have one-to-one relation, but you don't want to modify the domain class you are referencing, so that you don't have to introduce more complexity and/or migrate the old table.

To my mind, the 1st variant is useless and doesn't produce an error due to... lack of GORM developers time? ;)